# Expectation of a Markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, conditional-probability

Suppose I have a Markov chain $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with state space in the interval $[0,1]$. Suppose that for all $A\subseteq [0,1]$ it holds that
\begin{align}
P(X_n\in A|X_{n-1})=\int_AJ(X_{n-1}, y)dy,
\end{align}
where $J:[0,1]\times [0,1]\to \mathbb R$ is continuous symmetric and such that $\int_0^1J(x,y)dy=1$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.
Let $h:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$. Can I write the following equality?
\begin{align}
\mathbb E(h(X_n)\mathbb I_{(X_n\in A)})=&\int_0^1h(X_n)\mathbb I_{(X_n\in A)}P(dX_n)\\
=&\int_0^1\Big(\int_Ah(y)J(X_{n-1}, y)dy\Big)P(dX_{n-1})
\end{align}

Comment: It is correct but your notations are strange. $dX_n$ is not a standard notation.